# Kotlin's reflection: Simple variable extraction out of String

Tags: kotlin, reflection

I've read about reflection in both Kotlin and Java documentation & getattr in Python examples but they all seem to lack my use case:

I have variables of type `multableLiveData<boolean>`  like `repetitionOfElementsInNewExerciseAllowed` in a `ViewModel` class (Android programming) that I need to update from a different class like `HomeFragment`.
My unsexy approach was the following function in `ViewModel`:

```
    fun updateBoolElement (boolElementToUpdate:String, valueToUpdateWith:Boolean){
        when (boolElementToUpdate){
            "repetitionOfElementsInNewExerciseAllowed" -> repetitionOfElementsInNewExerciseAllowed.value=valueToUpdateWith
        }
    }
```

Instead of this I'm striving for a recursive approach to extract the variable's name whose value I want to change out of the string `boolElementToUpdate` like this (pseudo code):

```
    fun updateBoolElement (boolElementToUpdate:String, valueToUpdateWith:Boolean){
        getAttributeReferenceByName(boolElementToUpdate).value = valueToUpdateWith
    }
```

The way I would like to reuse the function is by calling it with different varible names then like

```
sharedViewModel.updateBoolElement("repetitionOfElementsInNewExerciseAllowed",repetitionOfElementsInNewExerciseAllowed)
```

or more abstractly

```
sharedViewModel.updateBoolElement("newVariableName",newBoolValue)
```

Is reflection or any other structure in Kotlin capable of doing such wizardry? Thanks for any hint!

Comment: How is this "recursive"? And why is the name of the property a string in the first place?

Comment: Regarding "My unsexy approach was...", code is not supposed to be "sexy". It is supposed to be readable and maintainable (among many other good qualities), and code involving reflection usually are neither.

Comment: I felt it was recursive through saving lines of code and being reused for different varibles rather than defining every situation in its when statement.

Well, I find space saving code like inline if statements sexy sometimes.

Comment: I edited the original question to show the purpose of reusing the function. What approach would you suppose to not having to fill up the when statement with new cases?

Comment: I don't think you have answered my second question? Why use a string in the first place? Where did that come from? Instead of `sharedViewModel.updateBoolElement("newVariableName",newBoolValue)` why not just `sharedViewModel.newVariableName = newBoolValue`? In your real code, are there something more going on in `updateBoolElement` than just a single assignment?

Comment: What I'm getting at is, if you are getting a string from a web API or something like that, then an approach using `KProperty` wouldn't work and you would need to use reflection, so knowing where this string comes from is very important. Does it come from somewhere external or does it only appear as literals in your source code?

Comment: Sorry, you're right!
I guess I myself came up with the idea of using a string. I originally read about updating values in ViewHolder via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69566274/change-string-value-in-viewmodel-on-button-click-in-kotlin-then-store-the-value which allows me to do more than just update the one variable value off from another class (although this is the only use case for the function at the moment).
I missed the mutableLiveData part this time so I just updated the question again.

Comment: I guess I could use KProperty as inferring the variable name out of a string would be an unnecessary part of the solution. If I only knew what parameters of KProperty to use..
I'm a bit lost with that :D

Comment: You might want to look up ‘[stringly](https://devcards.io/stringly-typed)-[typed](https://cocoacasts.com/the-danger-of-string-literals-and-stringly-typed-code) [code](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/31876/stringly-typed)’. (It's _not_ generally a good idea…)

Comment: In addition to the previous comments, you most likely will create a release of your android app with `Proguard` or `R8`. Class, member and methods name will be altered in build process unless you create keep rules for your methods, fields etc. "repetitionOfElementsInNewExerciseAllowed" would be like `c`.  Your code might not work as you expected.